# JS jQuery redirect with post values, without a <form>

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is a working example to redirect to a page sending post values

```
<a href="#" onClick="someFunc(); document.formname.submit();  return false;"  >click to post</a>
<form name="formname" action="/somepage.php"  method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="postName" value="something">
</form>
```

It works.  http://www.avramovic.info/razno/jquery/redirect/demo.php does the same thing by using js to create the form for you. jQuery().redirect('/redirurl/', {'arg1': 'value1', 'arg2': 'value2'});

How to accomplish the same thing without plugins?

Comment: How is this different from having a submit button in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the raw JS "version" of the code given:

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.style.display = "none";
form.action = "TARGET URL HERE";
form.method = "post";
// for each of your input variables:
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.name = "NAME HERE";
input.value = "VALUE HERE";
form.appendChild(input);
// After the last input:
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're using jquery:

```
var form = $('<form method="POST" action="my_action_url">' +
    '<input type="hidden" name="my_post_var" value="' + my_value_var + '" />' +
    '</form>');
$(document.body).append(form);
form.submit();
```

You can put it in a function too.